# How do I create a bash script to duplicate a file, swap first two columns and append to bottom of original file?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to write a bash script to duplicate the product-feed swapping the first two columns(sku, productId) and append it to feed. This is what I have so far but it does not seem to be working.

1. Duplicate the feed
2. Swap the first two columns
3. Append it to the original feed

1-Duplicate the feed--> `cd /var/ftp/JNM-01-020420/inbound/product-feed/en_US && cp ./*.csv /var/ftp/JNM-01-020420/inbound/product-feed/en_US/tmp`

2-Swap Columns--> `awk '{t=$1; $1=$2; $2=t; print;}' ./tmp`

3-Append to original feed --> `./tmp >> ./*.csv`

[Example of product feed for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEhow.png)

Comment: What do you expect `./tmp >> ./*.csv` to do?

Comment: At point 3, you should probably write "cat ./tmp >> ./*.csv". Also note that the whole script only works if the pattern "./*.csv" expands to a single file name.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I was thinking that would append the contents of the tmp file to the original CSV file.

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini Thanks, yup only one file in that directory and then it is deleted after ingestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on 150 MB file:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {print $2, $1}' inputfile.csv > col2-1.csv
cat col2-1.csv >> inputfile.csv
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you!